# base64 command on macOS returns wrong result

Tags: openssl, base64, macos-sierra

When calling `base64 <<< username:password` I get this result: `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK`.

When using that result in PostMan and issuing a request against a Basic Auth endpoint, I get back a 401.

When encoding `username:password` at https://www.base64encode.org, I get back this result: `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` and I can successfully use it against the Basic Auth endpoint from above.

If I use PostMan to generate the Basic Auth header passing in `username` and `password`, it generates the same base64 encoded string as https://www.base64encode.org.
I could also copy `username:password` into `testin.txt` and use `openssl` to create the base64 string:

`openssl base64 -in testin.txt -out testout.txt` returns `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK` which is the same wrong result as `base64` creates.

`openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Decoding `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK` gives `username:password\n`.

So my guess is that in both cases, you have a linefeed you weren't expecting. The `testin.txt` case is easy to solve (modify file, remove linefeed).

I expect the base64 case can be solved by using echo with the -n parameter to remove the linefeed:

```
echo -n username:password | base64 --encode
```

Comment: `echo username:password | base64` returns `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK` as well.

Comment: You are correct. Forgot you need to call `echo -n` to get rid of the linefeed.

Comment: btw do you have an idea where this extra linefeed comes from? I didn't copy/paste `username:password`

Comment: `echo` adds one unless you use `-n`. I assume the original `base64` gets it from the user pressing `enter`, but I don't know that to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

BASE64 file conversion on macOS (currently using OS X 10.14.6):

Encoding (PDF -> BASE64): cat aaa.pdf | base64 > aaa.base64

Decoding (BASE64 -> PDF): cat aaa.base64 | base64 -D >  aaa.pdf

I' using a PDF-File here as a sample. Of course you can use any file type.

Answer (score 0):

On mac OS 10.15.6

The `--encode` option is not available.
So this works without including the the --encode option.

```
echo -n username:password | base64
```